# MYSQL UNION - Producing unexpected Result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MYSQL Query

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT SUM(shop_order_price), p.category
from shop_orders so
INNER JOIN product p
on so.shop_order_product_id=p.product_id
WHERE so.shop_order_action = 'Sale'
AND so.brand = '53'
AND p.category = 'Mens'
AND so.shop_order_location = 'Bawtry'
AND so.shop_order_month = '05'  AND so.shop_order_year = '2014'

UNION ALL

    SELECT SUM(shop_order_price), p.category
    from shop_orders so
    INNER JOIN product p
    on so.shop_order_product_id=p.product_id
    WHERE so.shop_order_action = 'Sale'
    AND so.brand = '53'
    AND p.category= 'Ladies'
    AND so.shop_order_location = 'Bawtry'
    AND so.shop_order_month = '05'  AND so.shop_order_year = '2014'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SUM(shop_order_price), p.category
    from shop_orders so
    INNER JOIN product p
    on so.shop_order_product_id=p.product_id
    WHERE so.shop_order_action = 'Sale'
    AND so.brand = '53'
    AND so.shop_order_location = 'Bawtry'
    AND so.shop_order_month = '05'  AND so.shop_order_year = '2014'
```

Which produces the following result :

**RESULT**

```
SUM(shop_order_price)        category
--------------------         ---------

282.5                         Mens
751                           Ladies
1033.5                        Ladies
```

The SUM figures are correct, however, the bottom row displays 'Ladies' in the category column, even though no category is specified in the query.

My questions is can I get this final row to display `TOTAL` instead of `Ladies` ? So the result would appear as follows:

**Expected Result**

```
 SUM(shop_order_price)        category
    --------------------         ---------

    282.5                         Mens
    751                           Ladies
    1033.5                        TOTAL
```

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with the `WITH ROLLUP` modifier, to simplify your query:

```
SELECT SUM(shop_order_price), p.category
FROM shop_orders so
  INNER JOIN product p
  ON so.shop_order_product_id = p.product_id
WHERE so.shop_order_action = 'Sale'
  AND so.brand = '53'
  AND p.category IN ('Mens', 'Ladies')
  AND so.shop_order_location = 'Bawtry'
  AND so.shop_order_month = '05'  
  AND so.shop_order_year = '2014'
GROUP BY p.category
  WITH ROLLUP ;
```

If you want to not show `NULL` but `'TOTAL'`, this should better be in the application side. You can do it in SQL, wrapping query in a derived table - but I wouldn't use this:

```
SELECT
    sum_order_price, 
    COALESCE(category, 'TOTAL') AS category
FROM
  ( SELECT SUM(shop_order_price) AS sum_order_price,
           p.category
    FROM shop_orders so
      INNER JOIN product p
      ON so.shop_order_product_id = p.product_id
    WHERE so.shop_order_action = 'Sale'
      AND so.brand = '53'
      AND p.category IN ('Mens', 'Ladies')
      AND so.shop_order_location = 'Bawtry'
      AND so.shop_order_month = '05'  
      AND so.shop_order_year = '2014'
    GROUP BY p.category
      WITH ROLLUP
  ) AS dt ;
```

Comment: That's much more optimal - thanks. Is there anyway to show 'TOTAL' in the final row rather than _NULL_ ?

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer - would you mind explaining the reasons why you wouldn't use this?

Comment: It's pretty easy to format in the application side (if NULL, use TOTAL). Why complicate the SQL code?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an elegant solution, but you can try this. It is not assigning a column value to it, but has 'TOTAL' hardcoded in it, which I think should result in what you're after.

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT SUM(shop_order_price), p.category
from shop_orders so
INNER JOIN product p
on so.shop_order_product_id=p.product_id
WHERE so.shop_order_action = 'Sale'
AND so.brand = '53'
AND p.category = 'Mens'
AND so.shop_order_location = 'Bawtry'
AND so.shop_order_month = '05'  AND so.shop_order_year = '2014'

UNION ALL

    SELECT SUM(shop_order_price), p.category
    from shop_orders so
    INNER JOIN product p
    on so.shop_order_product_id=p.product_id
    WHERE so.shop_order_action = 'Sale'
    AND so.brand = '53'
    AND p.category= 'Ladies'
    AND so.shop_order_location = 'Bawtry'
    AND so.shop_order_month = '05'  AND so.shop_order_year = '2014'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SUM(shop_order_price), 'Total'
    from shop_orders so
    INNER JOIN product p
    on so.shop_order_product_id=p.product_id
    WHERE so.shop_order_action = 'Sale'
    AND so.brand = '53'
    AND so.shop_order_location = 'Bawtry'
    AND so.shop_order_month = '05'  AND so.shop_order_year = '2014'
```